# Android buttons placement

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a button and I am testing on a Samsung galaxy S3 the screen size according to android is normal now when I test it on the emulator with the normal screen size the buttons are placed in a different location and If I fix one the other get messed up or vice-versa

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/lefteyeoff"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>
```

Comment: what exactly do u mean by "normal screen size". Also if you could show us your layout what you are trying to achieve, it will be more easier to come up with a solution

Comment: Can you post full layout?

Comment: Can you please post a layout or a screenshot of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every gadget has its own resolution. When you are developing an app, you must consider that not everyone will have the same resolution as you might expect. Now that is yours to judge: Are you willing to support them all?

You seem to be stuck because your components position is relative one to another. There are two ways of positioning visual components in your activity: relative or absolute.

As I said before, knowing that nobody uses the same gadget with the same resolution, almost everybody uses relative positioning, because it allows for flexibility. This means that say your button A will be positioned in the top left corner, and the button B will be positioned to the right of button A. So if you move Button A, button B will follow. This seems to be your case right now. This is fine, if you know what you are doing.

Now there's also absolute positioning, which doesn't bother if things fit in the page or not, it displays them where you tell them to be. This might come in handy here and there, but I wouldn't even bother using this if you consider publishing the app.

Also, you can choose which device/resolution you are developing on through eclipse, and testing on through AVD, if both are set to the same device, you shouldn't have any troubles.

Answer (score 0):

have you declared multiple layouts for different screen sizes [multiple screen layouts in android](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) ? add a screen shot of your project layout directories so the issue could be understood more clearly and which layout you are using?